# Can Bixby have different views for different devices?

Tags: bixby

I am trying to have different input views for different devices in Bixby.

For example, on a Bixby tablet, i would want to allow the user to select multiple switch-inputs in a single screen. For the bixby speaker, on the other hand I would like to break this up and only prompt the user for one input at a time. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can definitely customize how information is presented to the user depending on the device being used.

First, you will need to declare the devices your capsule will support by defining the `targets` as shown below:

```
capsule {
  id (playground.example)
  version (0.1.0)
  format (3)
  runtime-flags {
    modern-prompt-rejection
    support-halt-effect-in-computed-inputs
  }
  targets {
    target (bixby-mobile-en-US)
    target (bixby-mobile-en-GB)
  }
}
```

Once your targets have been declared, you can create views for them. When you create a view in Bixby Studio, the "Create New File" pop-up window has the option for you to define the device that your view will be for. You will end up having multiple views presenting the same information across different devices and Bixby will use the correct one depending on the device.

Additionally, you can also use [Hands-Free List Navigation](https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/dev-guide/developers/enhancing-UX.list-navigation#adding-hands-free-list-navigation-to-views) to further refine the behavior of your views.