# Can I access device characteristic (e.g., screen size)?

Tags: bixby

Is there a way to detect user's device characteristics (e.g., screen size, rotation, etc)?

This answer seems only to be talking about very broad device type categories: [Can Bixby have different views for different devices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55799725)

Answer (score 0):

In **$vivContext** there is a property `deviceModel`.

By adding **$vivContext** as an input argument in JS function, you can access the device model code. You can read more in [Passing User Context Information in the Developer's Guide](https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/dev-guide/developers/actions.js-actions#passing-user-context-information)

However, I believe there is no way to determine which rotation mode user is currently in and dynamically adjust view.

There is also the case that user adjust rotation after executing the capsule, thus the view is already rendered.

Comment: Thanks. So, yes, $vivContext gives me something like: bixby-mobile.  But there is no info about screen size, for example. Is that available anywhere?  Alternately, is there a list of device types and the range of characteristics? For example, are a tablet (of whatever size) and a phone (of whatever size) both "bixby-mobile"?

Comment: I was thinking on actual device, deviceModel: The specific device model of the client. Example: SM-G965N. Is that not the case?

Comment: Yes, it does. (I was only using the simulator.) . Not sure what the right approach is - I assume there are a lot of devices. What is the approach if we want to change the layout depending on, for example, screen dimensions?

Comment: I am afraid there is no easy solution for that at the moment. I believe you can build a view for any specified model number, but we don't have a list to classify the model number for you.

Comment: Okay. I'll make a feature request to pass along some basic device characteristics with $vivContext.